# Can't upload Dask dataframe to BigQuery (Arrow did not recognize python value)

Tags: google-bigquery, dask

I'm trying to upload a Dask dataframe to BigQuery table.

I cast numeric fields to float and the remaining fields stayed as 'object'.

And the error that load_table_from_dataframe() throws is this:

```
> Name: name, dtype: object Dask Name: try_loc, 49 graph layers with
> type Series: did not recognize Python value type when inferring an Arrow data type
```

I've already tried to cast *objects* as *string*, but **it does not work anyways**.

This is my code:

```
df = dd.read_sql_table(table_name= table_name, index_col='id', con=f'{dialect}+{driver}://{username}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{database}', meta=df_to_cast)
df = df.fillna(0)
df = df.reset_index()

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(PATHS.GCP_KEYS)
client = bigquery.Client(project='datalakedesarrollo',credentials=credentials)

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(autodetect= True)
client.load_table_from_dataframe(dataframe=df, destination='datalakedesarrollo.dwh_testing_1.test3', job_config = job_config)
```

According to what I found about PyArrow (or Arrow) the schema mapping between arrow and a dask dataframe (or Pandas) is not always perfect, but I used autodetect=True and all the dtypes from the dd are perfectly cast (floats and strings).

Any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/bigquery/latest/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client#google_cloud_bigquery_client_Client_load_table_from_dataframe), `load_table_from_dataframe`'s input must be a pandas dataframe, not dask.

Maybe you can do something like

```
df.map_partitions(lambda d: client.insert_rows_from_dataframe(d, ...))
```

Comment: thank you! @mdurant it seems to work, I have to make some transformations in my data but I think this will work. Thank you! Any other recommendation to upload data efficiently from dask to big query? I've read something about writing a parquet file (or csv) to GCS and then load it to bigquery from GCS. I'm exploring alternatives for my pipeline

Comment: I have no specific bigquery experience. Yes, writing parquet (df.to_parquet) is a common and well-trodden operation for dask.